# What is the best way to check the user's permissions for a specific record within a visual workflow?

Tags: permissions, sharing, flow

I have a flow that adds products to an Opportunity, but I want to be able to make sure that the user running the flow actually has permission to edit the Opp before continuing with the flow.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How about an apex plugin?

Comment: Do the FastLookups not respect the salesforce security model?   I beleive they run in User context, but not 100%.

Comment: We have lots of cases where a user can read records that they can't edit. In those cases, they might try the "Add Product" button, it will fail in an unhandled exception.